# User cannot see "Available" as an option in Salesforce chat omni channel

Tags: liveagent, chat, omnichannel

when a user logs into salesforce chat and trying to make him available for live chat, "Available" is not an option for them. They have all the required access like they are service cloud users, chat user and is assigned to that specific queue. what causes this issue. The other user with same profile and role can see it. I have tried comparing both user records and didn't find any differences. Does it have anything to do with chat visitors/chat transcript object access?

Comment: Have you checked that you are not hitting the [API usage limit](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000334374&type=1)

Comment: There we re no such issues. I have missed assigning them a permission set which fixed this issue.

Answer (score 0):

This has been resolved after assigning users a custom permission set. I will post permission set details.